# SQL Replace NULL Values with Own text

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to display the keyboard players from a list of bands, and I've been able to using the following SQL:

```
SELECT BAND.NAME AS Band_Name, KBPLAYER.NAME AS Keyboard_Player
FROM BAND
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT M.NAME, MO.BID
    FROM MEMBEROF MO, MEMBER M
    WHERE MO.INSTRUMENT='keyboards'
    AND M.MID=MO.MID
    ) KBPLAYER
ON BAND.BID=KBPLAYER.BID
ORDER BY BAND.NAME, KBPLAYER.NAME
```

The above query displays the names of all the band and the keyboard player (if any) in that band, but I also want to display 'No KeyBoard Players' for those bands that don't have a keyboard player. How can I achieve this? Please let me know if you need me to furnish with details of the table structure.

**Update:** Please note that I'm not able to use any of the `SQL3 procedures` (`COALESCE, CASE, IF..ELSE`). It needs to conform strictly to SQL3 standard.

Comment: I've just updated my tags.

Comment: Just check NVL, it might help you

Comment: Is it giving NULL for you if there is no keyboard player?

Comment: It is not showing NULL; just an empty field, indicating it is null.

Comment: So you want to replace empty field to some text?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @ajitksharma: `NVL` is, AFAIK, an Oracle-ism. The standard approach is to use `COALESCE` and I'm pretty sure Oracle supports that too.

Comment: Are you certain that SQL:1999 (AKA SQL3) doesn't have COALESCE and CASE? I find it very difficult to believe that CTEs were supported but CASE and COALESCE were not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've decided to do it differently since I wasn't going anywhere with the above SQL. I'll appreciate if anyone has suggestions to make for the above SQL with the set constraints.

```
SELECT 
  band.name AS Band_Name, 'NULL' AS Keyboard_Player
FROM 
  memberof
INNER JOIN 
 member
ON 
  memberof.mid = member.mid 
FULL JOIN 
  band
ON 
  memberof.bid = band.bid 
AND 
  instrument = 'keyboards'

WHERE  
  member.name IS NULL 

UNION

SELECT 
  band.name AS Band_Name, member.name AS Keyboard_Player
FROM 
  memberof
INNER JOIN 
 member
ON 
  memberof.mid = member.mid 
FULL JOIN 
  band
ON 
  memberof.bid = band.bid 
WHERE
  instrument = 'keyboards'
```

Answer (score 31):

Use the [coalesce](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function. This function returns the first of it's arguments that are not null. Eg:

```
COALESCE(KBPLAYER.NAME,'No KeyBoard Players') AS Keyboard_Player
```

Comment: That works - except part of my assignment's requirement is that I'm not able to use COALESCE. Is there an alternative that I can look into?

Comment: Are you allowed to use a case statement? And please update your question with any constraints like functions you are not allowed to use

Comment: Updated. Please refer to above.

Comment: Thanks for introducing to me `COALESCE`, this will come useful in another one of my assignments.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment to replace empty string to some text, the simple solution is to use case statement like below.

```
SELECT BAND.NAME AS Band_Name, 
CASE WHEN KBPLAYER.NAME = '' THEN 'No Player' ELSE KBPLAYER.NAME END AS Keyboard_Player
FROM BAND
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT M.NAME, MO.BID
    FROM MEMBEROF MO, MEMBER M
    WHERE MO.INSTRUMENT='keyboards'
    AND M.MID=MO.MID
    ) KBPLAYER
ON BAND.BID=KBPLAYER.BID
ORDER BY BAND.NAME, KBPLAYER.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks Naveen - but I've just updated my question with specific constraints, as advised by Harmic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
    SELECT BAND.NAME AS Band_Name, 
ISNULL(NULLIF(KBPLAYER.NAME,''),'No KeyBoard Players') AS Keyboard_Player
    FROM BAND
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT M.NAME, MO.BID
        FROM MEMBEROF MO, MEMBER M
        WHERE MO.INSTRUMENT='keyboards'
        AND M.MID=MO.MID
        ) KBPLAYER
    ON BAND.BID=KBPLAYER.BID
    ORDER BY BAND.NAME, KBPLAYER.NAME
```

Comment: I'm getting ERROR: function isnull(text, unknown) does not exist'.

Comment: ISNULL is checking if the value of column is NULL, but in this case it has empty string. So Is null is not going to work.

Comment: Because of that, I've added the `NULLIF` see above query

Comment: Oh yeah.. I overlooked into it, its fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions will not handle an empty string.  This one will.

COALESCE(NULLIF(KBPLAYER.NAME,''),'No KeyBoard Players') AS Keyboard_Player

Answer (score -1):

If NVL is allowed, below should work.

```
NVL(KBPLAYER.NAME, 'No KeyBoard Players')
```

Comment: I'm getting 'ERROR:  function nvl(character varying, unknown) does not exist'.

Comment: The question is tagged postgresql - NVL is non-standard and not supported by postgresql. coalesce is the equivalent.